# Loading data from local file into Excel Add In

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-addins

I am trying to load data from a local CSV file into into my Excel add in, in order to populate a worksheet with the data from said CSV file. Here is the current code that I have...

```
function readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                return rawFile.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

When this code is called, I receive an "Access in denied" error in the `rawFile.Open("GET...` line. How do I fix this?

The `file` parameter passed in is:

> "file:///C:/path/to/file/data.csv"

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try `WorksheetCollection.addFromBase64` API.
I prepared a gist for you.
https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/7038ef449790b173b41f17165a2222ba

This API is now in beta preview.

Here is the document for this API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcollection?view=excel-js-preview#addfrombase64-base64file--sheetnamestoinsert--positiontype--relativeto-